# Lift up all occurrences of a type in a nested dictionary to a top level key

Tags: python, dictionary

I have a need in a project to find all of a given type in a nested dictionary and move them all to a top level key in the same dictionary.

So far I have the below code, which seems to work. In the example I'm looking for all the items that are integers and moving them to a `'numbers'` key.

I'd prefer it if the `lift_numbers_to_top` function made and returned a copy of the dictionary rather than editing it in place, but I haven't been able to work out a nice way to pass the copy and the numbers back from the recursive function to itself, if that makes sense.

```
a_dictionary = {
    "one": 1,
    "two": 2,
    "text": "Hello",
    "more_text": "Hi",
    "internal_dictionary": {
        "three": 3,
        "two": 2,
        "even_more_text": "Hey",
        "another_internal_dictionary": {
            "four": 4,
            "five": 5,
            "last_text": "howdy"
        }
    }
}


def extract_integers(dictionary, level_key=None):
    numbers = {}
    for key in dictionary:
        if type(dictionary[key]) == int:
            numbers[level_key + "__" + key if level_key else key] = dictionary[key]
    return numbers


def lift_numbers_to_top(dictionary, level_key=None):
    numbers = {}
    if type(dictionary) == dict:
        numbers = extract_integers(dictionary, level_key)
        for key in numbers:
            keyNumber = key.split('__')[-1]
            del dictionary[keyNumber]
        for key in dictionary:
            numbers = {**numbers, **lift_numbers_to_top(dictionary[key], key)}
    return numbers


a_dictionary['numbers'] = lift_numbers_to_top(a_dictionary)
print(a_dictionary)
```

Result:

```
{
    'text': 'Hello',
    'more_text': 'Hi',
    'internal_dictionary': {
        'even_more_text': 'Hey',
        'another_internal_dictionary': {
            'last_text': 'howdy'
        },
    },
    'numbers': {
        'one': 1,
        'two': 2,
        'internal_dictionary__two': 2,
        'internal_dictionary__three': 3,
        'another_internal_dictionary__four': 4,
        'another_internal_dictionary__five': 5,
    }
}
```

Comment: Please post your desired output.

Comment: @Sarcoma: it helps us determine if we are understanding the problem statement, *and* verify that our solution matches the expectations. Please add it to your post.

Comment: Sure thing, there you go. Just reading through your answer, quite a few things I've not encountered a lot.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a match function to determine what to lift, and pass along the target object where you move key-value pairs to to recursive calls. If that target is missing, you know the current call is for the top-level. The match function should return the new key for the new dictionary.

To produce a new dictionary, just produce a new dictionary and put recursion results into that object.

I prefer to use [`@singledispatch()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functools.html#functools.singledispatch) to handle different types when recursing:

```
from functools import singledispatch

@singledispatch
def lift_values(obj, match, targetname=None, **kwargs):
    """Lift key-value pairs from a nested structure to the top

    For key-value pairs anywhere in the nested structure, if
    match(path, value) returns a value other than `None`, the 
    key-value pair is moved to the top-level dictionary when targetname
    is None, or to a new dictionary stored under targetname is not None,
    using the return value of the match function as the key. path
    is the tuple of all keys and indices leading to the value.

    For example, for an input 

        {'foo': True, 'bar': [{'spam': False, 'ham': 42}]}

    and the match function lambda p, v: p if isinstance(v, bool) else None
    and targetname "flags", this function returns

        {'flags': {('foo',): True, ('bar', 0, 'spam'): False}, 'bar': [{'ham': 42}]}

    """
    # leaf nodes, no match testing needed, no moving of values
    return obj

@lift_values.register(list)
def _handle_list(obj, match, _path=(), **kwargs):
    # list values, no lifting, just passing on the recursive call
    return [lift_values(v, match, _path=_path + (i,), **kwargs)
            for i, v in enumerate(obj)]

@lift_values.register(dict)
def _handle_list(obj, match, targetname=None, _path=(), _target=None):
    result = {}
    if _target is None:
        # this is the top-level object, key-value pairs are lifted to
        # a new dictionary stored at this level:
        if targetname is not None:
            _target = result[targetname] = {}
        else:
            # no target name? Lift key-value pairs into the top-level
            # object rather than a separate sub-object.
            _target = result

    for key, value in obj.items():
        new_path = _path + (key,)
        new_key = match(new_path, value)
        if new_key is not None:
            _target[new_key] = value
        else:
            result[key] = lift_values(
                value, match, _path=new_path, _target=_target)

    return result
```

I included a dispatch function for lists; your sample doesn't use lists, but these are common in JSON data structures so I anticipate you probably want it anyway.

The match function must accept two arguments, the path to the object this key-value pair was found in, and the value. It should return a new key to use or `None` if not to lift the value.

For your case, the match function would be:

```
def lift_integers(path, value):
    if isinstance(value, int):
        return '__'.join(path[-2:])

result = lift_values(a_dictionary, lift_integers, 'numbers')
```

Demo on your sample input dictionary:

```
>>> from pprint import pprint
>>> def lift_integers(path, value):
...     if isinstance(value, int):
...         return '__'.join(path[-2:])
...
>>> lift_values(a_dictionary, lift_integers, 'numbers')
{'numbers': {'one': 1, 'two': 2, 'internal_dictionary__three': 3, 'internal_dictionary__two': 2, 'another_internal_dictionary__four': 4, 'another_internal_dictionary__five': 5}, 'text': 'Hello', 'more_text': 'Hi', 'internal_dictionary': {'even_more_text': 'Hey', 'another_internal_dictionary': {'last_text': 'howdy'}}}
>>> pprint(_)
{'internal_dictionary': {'another_internal_dictionary': {'last_text': 'howdy'},
                         'even_more_text': 'Hey'},
 'more_text': 'Hi',
 'numbers': {'another_internal_dictionary__five': 5,
             'another_internal_dictionary__four': 4,
             'internal_dictionary__three': 3,
             'internal_dictionary__two': 2,
             'one': 1,
             'two': 2},
 'text': 'Hello'}
```

Personally, I'd use the full path as the key in the lifted dictionary to avoid name clashes; either by joining the full `path` into a new string key with some unique delimiter, or just by making the `path` tuple itself the new key:

```
>>> lift_values(a_dictionary, lambda p, v: p if isinstance(v, int) else None, 'numbers')
{'numbers': {('one',): 1, ('two',): 2, ('internal_dictionary', 'three'): 3, ('internal_dictionary', 'two'): 2, ('internal_dictionary', 'another_internal_dictionary', 'four'): 4, ('internal_dictionary', 'another_internal_dictionary', 'five'): 5}, 'text': 'Hello', 'more_text': 'Hi', 'internal_dictionary': {'even_more_text': 'Hey', 'another_internal_dictionary': {'last_text': 'howdy'}}}
>>> pprint(_)
{'internal_dictionary': {'another_internal_dictionary': {'last_text': 'howdy'},
                         'even_more_text': 'Hey'},
 'more_text': 'Hi',
 'numbers': {('internal_dictionary', 'another_internal_dictionary', 'five'): 5,
             ('internal_dictionary', 'another_internal_dictionary', 'four'): 4,
             ('internal_dictionary', 'three'): 3,
             ('internal_dictionary', 'two'): 2,
             ('one',): 1,
             ('two',): 2},
 'text': 'Hello'}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, `@singledispatch` is super cool, I'm working with what you've provided to see what I can get working. I've added the desired results, which are a little different from your output.

Comment: @Sarcoma: I've updated my answer to adjust for the target. `singledispatch` is not strictly needed here, but simplifies the implementation a little in that you don't have to do any type checks in the implementation.

Comment: It looks like it gives you a way to switch the functions out based on the type of the first argument, is that right? Thanks for updating the code, however I'm handling duplicates that might turn up, there are two `'two'` keys. I'm prepending the parent key to the nested keys to avoid losing data. I'll see if I can suss it out.

Comment: @Sarcoma: ah, of course, I missed that. Why not the full path, however? And I'd use a tuple for the keys in that case.

Comment: Full path would be better actually, I've tried adding a parent parameter to track it, but I'm tying myself in knots at the moment.

Comment: I have it working with the parent prepended, I'll look at chaining the parent key now.

Comment: @Sarcoma: I've updated my approach to handle your case and more.

Comment: Ah I see what you mean about the tuples now, I had just kept building the string up on each iteration. Thanks so much for the help, really nice solution.

Answer (score 0):

You can use walk through the dict recursively and pop all elements with values as an `int` to create a new dict

```
>>> def extract(d):
...     new_d = {}
...     for k,v in d.items():
...         if type(v) == int:
...             new_d[k] = d[k]
...         elif type(v) == dict:
...             for k2,v2 in extract(v).items():
...                 new_d[k2 if '__' in k2 else k+'__'+k2] = v2
...     return new_d
... 
>>> a_dictionary['numbers'] = extract(a_dictionary)
>>> pprint(a_dictionary)
{'internal_dictionary': {'another_internal_dictionary': {'last_text': 'howdy'},
                         'even_more_text': 'Hey'},
 'more_text': 'Hi',
 'numbers': {'another_internal_dictionary__five': 5,
             'another_internal_dictionary__four': 4,
             'internal_dictionary__three': 3,
             'internal_dictionary__two': 2,
             'one': 1,
             'two': 2},
 'text': 'Hello'}
```

Comment: Thanks but I do not want the additional nesting. It's for an API to collect some useful data into a nice list.

Comment: @Sarcoma. Sorry. Misread the question. Have updated the answer

Comment: Nice and concise, I think this still mutates the original dictionary with `d.pop(k)`. That's the thing I'm trying to avoid, it's the problem I have in my own example.

Comment: `for k,v in list(d.items()):` does this create a copy of the dictionary items as a list of tuples so that you can modify the dictionary in the loop?

Comment: Changed the `d.pop(k)` to `d[k]`, That should avoid `d` getting modified. As we are not modifying `d`, we can just iterate over it as `for k,v in d.items():`

Comment: Please don't use `type(obj) == class`. Use `isinstance(obj, class)` instead, so *subclasses* can pass the test too. If you must restrict a type check to a specific class and exclude all else, use `is` to verify the class object, so `type(obj) is class`.

Comment: Your code generates *just the `numbers` dictionary*, but never removes the integer values from their old locations. The code posted **can't produce the output shown** because of that. The OP wanted a solution that generates a whole new dictionary, and not one that alters `a_dictionary` in place.

Comment: See https://gist.github.com/mjpieters/bd2fed2ab251a91d59d4dc56627a905c for the actual output this answer produces, note that the keys `'one'` through to `'five'` are all still present in their original locations.